# Type cannot be found from T4 template

Tags: c#, t4

I want to go through all values of the following enum

```
namespace T4Demo
{
  public enum Ord
  {
    First,
    Second
  }
}
```

in my template

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<# 
  var arr = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(System.DayOfWeek));
  foreach(var it in arr)
  {
    string name = it.ToString();
    string value = ((int)it).ToString();
#>
    <#= name #>(<#= value #>)
<#
  }
#>
```

in order to output them. It works fine with `System.DayOfWeek` and outputs

```
Sunday(0)
Monday(1)
Tuesday(2)
Wednesday(3)
Thursday(4)
Friday(5)
Saturday(6)
```

but trying to use `Ord` instead results in an error saying that the type or namespace 'Ord' cannot be found. If I prefix it with `T4Demo.` or if I add `<#@ import namespace="T4Demo" #>` in the template it tells me that 'T4Demo' cannot be found. What have I overlooked?

**EDIT:**

This is what IntelliSense gives me when trying to enter `T4Demo`. My own types do not get listed here... So I must be missing some using etc.

[image: IntelliSense]

Comment: are you using vs2015? i've recently prototyped a project to solve issues like this because for issues like this t4 is very uncomfortable. It depends on roslyn + latest msbuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nicolas Repiquet pointed out, the T4 template is a program on its own. The resolution was consequently to add `<#@ assembly name="$(TargetPath)" #>` in the template header which makes all my types from the same project visible within the template.

Important to know is the fact that whenever the project is changed and recompiled the template will not be rerun. So in my case, whenever I change the enum in code, I compile and select 'Run custom tool' from the context menu of the template file in the Solution Explorer to ensure that the output of my template matches the enum changes in code.

Comment: So your T4 template depends on your project output, but your project depends on code generated by your T4 template. Silent circular reference !

Comment: No, in fact I'm generating a Matlab enumeration definition from the C# enum definition. Above I posted just a simplified version of what I want to be written by the template as my output.

Answer (score 1):

Your T4 template is a program on its own, and the types you defined in your main program are not part of it.

There is no easy way to get around that. You might use the [T4 include directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586949.aspx) to include the enum code in the template code, but you'll probably gonna fight with it a little.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifing the exact location of your enum, just like you did with the day of the week Arry.

```
System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(System.DayOfWeek));
```

Should then become

```
System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumLocation.Ord));
```

**Edit**

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
@model <#= ViewDataTypeName #> // Added this line
<# 
  var arr = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(System.DayOfWeek)); // This line is no longer required
  foreach(var item in model) // Changed this line
  {
    string name = item.ToString();
    string value = ((int)it).ToString();
#>
    <#= name #>(<#= value #>)
<#
  }
#>
```

Comment: Unfortunately (like I wrote in my question) if I prefix it with `T4Demo.` or it tells me that 'T4Demo' cannot be found.

Comment: Have you tried giving the enum as item to be scaffolded? `@model <#= ViewDataTypeName #>` and then `foreach(var item in model)`

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what I should change exactly. Can you please provide a complete sample? Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if this gives you any errors, I am kind of intrigued by this :).

Comment: It gives me the same error as before: Type not found.

Comment: In what format do you give the input, just the enum or a collection of enum values?

Comment: The error occurs on the line with @model. Intellisense does neigher propose any of my own types. Therefore it doesn't make a difference in what "format" I give the input.

Comment: It does, does the error come after using the template? Or do you get it while making it?

Comment: Well, I want to execute the template anytime I save it - which it does by default. I am not running the template from code.

Comment: In what kin of application are you using it then? I was kind of assuming you used it as a scaffolding template, but if that is not the case my solution won't work.